# PostgreSQL Group by array of daterange

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have a *massive* table with records that all have a date and a price:

```
id | date | price | etc...
```

And then I have a list of random date ranges, never with the same length:

```
ARRAY [
    daterange('2020-11-02','2020-11-05'), 
    daterange('2020-11-15','2020-11-20')
]
```

How would I most efficiently go about summing and grouping the records by their existence in one of the ranges, like so:

```
range                   | sum
------------------------------------------
[2020-11-02,2020-11-05) | 125.55
[2020-11-15,2020-11-20) | 566.12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the array, `left join` the table on dates that are contained in ranges, and finally aggregate:

```
select x.rg, sum(t.price) sum_price
from unnest($1) x(rg)
left join mytable t on x.rg @> t.date 
group by x.rg
```

`$1` represents the array of `daterange`s that you want to pass to the query.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!